# Почему возникла ошибка MySQL "Incorrect date value"?

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, post, form

**Возникла ошибка**

```
Incorrect date value: 'Array' for column 'дата сдачи' at row 1
```

Вот мой код :

```
<form action=' ' method='post' >
<?php
include '../db.php';
{   /* выборка группы */
    $qwer =("SELECT * FROM  группа");
    $sql = mysql_query($qwer) or die(mysql_error());    
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    echo  "<select name='group'>";
    do {
        echo "<option value=" .$row['номер групп'].">".$row['номер групп']."</option>";
    } while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql));
    echo "</select>";
}

{   /*выборка дисциплины*/
    $qw =("SELECT * FROM  дисциплины");
    $sq = mysql_query($qw) or die(mysql_error());    
    $ro = mysql_fetch_array($sq);
    echo  "<select name='дисциплина'>"."<option >"."Выборка"."</option>";
        do   
        {
            echo "<option value=" .$ro['дисциплина'].">".$ro['дисциплина']."</option>";
    }
    while($ro = mysql_fetch_array($sq));
    echo "</select>";
}
?>
Следить за посещением лекций? 
да  <input type="radio" name='vlec' value='On'/>
нет <input type="radio" name='vlec' value='off' checked="checked"/><br>
    <input type='submit' name='redgr' >
<?php
if(isset($_POST['redgr']) && $_POST['vlec'] =='On') {
    $g=$_POST['group'];
    $d=$_POST['дисциплина'];
    echo $g,$d;
    echo "Сколько лекций
        <input type='text' name='collec' value='numberl'>
        <input type='submit' name='n' >";
    echo "";
}

if(isset($_POST['n'])) { 
    $ks=$_POST['collec'];
    echo $ks.'<br>';
    for($i=0; $i<$ks; $i++) {
        echo $i . " " . "введите дату занятия<input type='date' name='calendar[]'>
        Введите тип<input type='text' name='type[]'><br>"." введите норме<input type='text' name='name[]'><br>";

    }
    echo $ks."<input type='submit' name='dd2' />";
}

if( isset( $_POST['dd2'])) {
    $g=$_POST['group'];
    $d=$_POST['дисциплина'];
    $typew=$_POST['type'];
    $namew=$_POST['name'];
    $value=$_POST['calendar'];
    $rt=$_POST['calendar'];

    print_r ($rt) ." не работает че то<br>";
    do {    
        $adstudent = ("INSERT INTO `назначенные` (`номер группы`,`дисциплина`,`тип работы`,`имя работы`,`дата сдачи`) 
            VALUES ('$g','$d','$typew','$namew','$value')");
            $studentsql = mysql_query($adstudent) or die(mysql_error());
    } while( print_r($rt ));

    $typew=$_POST['type'];
    $namew=$_POST['name'];
    echo $typew;
}

echo '<form>';
?>
```

Comment: во первых - не используйте расширение mysql (используйте mysqli или PDO), а во вторых - русские имена переменных, таблиц, баз данных.

Comment: и **форматируйте код**

Comment: Mysql вам же русским языком говорит - вы пытаетесь добавить запись, внешний ключ которой требует существование записи в таблице 'работ'.

Раз появляется данная ошибка, значит запись с (дисциплина, тип работы, имя работы) отсутствует в таблице работ.

Либо надо добавить сначала в эту таблицу соответствующую запись, либо перепроектировать БД - например, создать внешние ключи на другие таблицы (из которых берете значения)

Comment: ncorrect date value: 'Array' for column 'дата сдачи' at row 1 это потому что с ключами добавляет?
как нормально сделать?

Comment: @Stein_ вам какой-то бред подсказали. При ошибке работы с ключами mysql выдаст совсем другой результат. И да, zb прав, не используйте mysql. Еще лучше - поставьте php7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы передаете массив в строку. массив в php вашей версии превращается в строчку Array. значение "Array" - это не то, что вы можете записать в поле типа date/timestamp  и т.д.

ваше $value  приходит из  html-формы из поля `name='calendar[]'`(не знаю, зачем вы так запутали, почему нельзя было назвать переменную $calendar?)

php интерпретирует такие поля как массивы.

при попытке превратить массив в строку, вы получаете строчку "array" - это стандартное поведение в php5.

вот и вся разгадка. можете сделать `var_dump($value);` перед инсертом в базу, и все сами увидите

проверка:

`php -r '$a=array(); echo $a;'`,

получаем предупреждение php :

`PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in Command line code on line 1`

вывод:

`Array`

P.S.
(комментарий к комментарию)
не вижу связи между

> Вы пытаетесь добавить запись, внешний ключ которой требует существование записи в таблице 'работ'.

и сообщением

> “Incorrect date value”

P.P.S.

если бы вы включили предупреждения, вы бы сами заметили и погуглили бы ошибку в коде.

P.P.P.S.
никогда больше не давайте колонке в бд имя с пробелом. Это недопустимо. `field_name`, а не `field name`.